# How to use image_summary to view images from different batches in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow

I am curious about how image_summary works. There is a parameter called max_images, which controls how many images would be shown. However it seems the summary only displays images from one batch. If we use bigger value of max_iamges, we will just view more images from the batch. Is there a way I can view for example one image from each batch?

Answer (score 8):

To view one image from each batch, you need to fetch the result of the [`tf.image_summary()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#image_summary) op every time you run a step. For example, it you have the following setup:

```
images = ...
loss = ...
optimizer = ...

train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
image_summary_t = tf.image_summary(images.name, images, max_images=1)

sess = tf.Session()
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(...)
sess.run(init_op)
```

...you could set up your training loop to capture one image per iteration as follows:

```
for _ in range(10000):
    _, image_summary = sess.run([train_op, image_summary_t])
    summary_writer.add_summary(image_summary)
```

Note that capturing summaries on each batch might be inefficient, and you should probably only capture the summary periodically for faster training.

**EDIT:** The above code writes a separate summary for each image, so your log will contain all of the images, but they will not all be visualized in TensorBoard. If you want to combine your summaries to visualize images from multiple batches, you could do the following:

```
combined_summary = tf.Summary()
for i in range(10000):
    _, image_summary = sess.run([train_op, image_summary_t])
    combined_summary.MergeFromString(image_summary)
    if i % 10 == 0:
        summary_writer.add_summary(combined_summary)
        combined_summary = tf.Summary()
```

Comment: I tried your method, but it showed only one picture. I am wondering what your result looks like?

Comment: I added a bit to the comment that might help you visualize the different images.

Comment: Thanks for your notes, but it seems still not working. The log file was only 820k, which could contain so many images. By the way, I could find reference about tf.Summary() and MergeFromString method, is this the only way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you need a [`summary_writer.flush()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/train.html#SummaryWriter.flush) call? `MergeFromString()` is a protobuf library method. You could also try accumulating one image from each batch into a [`tf.FIFOQueue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#FIFOQueue) and using `dequeue_many()` to assemble a tensor of images from different batches.

Comment: @mrry can you expend a little on `.MergeFromString` ? For exemple let's say you have defined image_summary for a tensor of weights [32,5,5,3], inside a scope outside the training loop. 
And that you are feeding a merged object wich is the combination of all the summaries  (`merge_all_summaries()`). Where would you write your code MergeFromString ? You want to have 320 images at the end (32 images every 100 steps).

Comment: It does not seem to work for me. Does it work for anybody?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by creating a new `image_summary` op for each batch. i.e. I went from something that looked like:

```
train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('summary_dir')
img = tf.image_summary("fooImage", img_data)
for i in range(N_BATCHES):
  summary, _ = sess.run([img, train_step])
  train_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
```

(Which, frustratingly, was not doing what I expected.) To...

```
train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('summary_dir')
for i in range(N_BATCHES):
  # Images are sorted in lexicographic order, so zero-pad the name
  img = tf.image_summary("fooImage{:06d}".format(i), img_data)
  summary, _ = sess.run([img, train_step])
  train_writer.add_summary(summary)
```