# How to use summaries on tensorflow's retrain inception final layer

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have been sucessfully using [tensorflow's tutorial on retraining](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html) the final layer to handle new classes and I would like to add some summaries to check how the cross-entropy is evolving.

I have looked into the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html) and tried to replicate it but I wasn't successful. 
Right now, I can launch tensorboard and see the graph but nothing else is displayed on the other tabs (events, images, histograms).

Has anyone added summaries to the inception retraining example?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added TensorBoard summaries to the stock code for the TensorFlow image retraining [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html). You can checkout the [latest TensorFlow code on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) if you want to use TensorBoard with the tutorial. I also wrote a [blog post](http://maxmelnick.com/2016/07/04/visualizing-tensorflow-retrain.html) about it if you're interested in more details.

Comment: Great. I will look into that.

Comment: hi @Max, Is there any way to display images after training, I used this retraining example to trained a list of place's photo, but I don't know how to display these trained images in the tensorboard

Comment: @khuebui I haven't added image summaries in Tensorboard in awhile, but this post should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005691/how-to-use-image-summary-to-view-images-from-different-batches-in-tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

To get scalar summaries (etc) to display, you need to do the following four things:

1. Add summary nodes to your graph (e.g. a `tf.scalar_summary` or `tf.histogram_summary`)
2. Merge all those summaries into a single op `tf.merge_all_summaries`
3. Run the summary op as a part of the training loop, and store the output
4. Pass the outputted summary string into a `tf.train.SummaryWriter`.

Are you doing all those steps?