# Accessing all written tensorflow image summaries

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

Given: A tensorflow model which outputs a grayscale image, given an input image.

I would like to keep track of qualitative results over time and save an image summary every given number of training steps:

```
    ...
    tf.image_summary('prediction', img_prediction) 
    summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    ...
    for i in range(10000):
        if i == 0 or i % 10 != 0:
            _ = sess.run([train_op])
        else:
            summary_str, _, _,... = sess.run([summary_op, ...])
            summmary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, i)
```

Whenever I execute the summary operation, the previous image in Tensorboard is replaced with the new one.

I would like to **inspect the images from prior iterations where I saved summaries** in Tensorboard as well. Is there a way to concatenate new images to the previous images in Tensorboard without blowing up the size of the summaries?

In a related question ([How to use image_summary to view images from different batches in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005691/how-to-use-image-summary-to-view-images-from-different-batches-in-tensorflow)) it was proposed to combine the images summaries from batches between summary writes and then write the merged summary:

```
combined_summary = tf.Summary()
for i in range(10000):
    _, image_summary = sess.run([train_op, image_summary_t])
    combined_summary.MergeFromString(image_summary)
    if i % 10 == 0:
        summary_writer.add_summary(combined_summary)
        combined_summary = tf.Summary()
```

The way I understand the code, this would also replace the merged 10 image summaries after each write. 
I assume that leaving out

```
        combined_summary = tf.Summary()
```

would achieve my goal, but blow up the size of the saved summaries over time and make the contents of the written summaries very redundant.